# Load balancer does not have available server for client. How to solve?

Tags: configuration, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I noticed that many people asked the same question, But I tried their ways, but my problem is still there.

I use spring-boot + eureka + zuul,

spring.cloud.version: 2.0.2.RELEASE

Here is the Eureka server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
@Slf4j
public class EurekaServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
        log.info("-- EurekaServerApplication started --");
    }
}
```

and the application.yml for eureka server:

```
server:
port: 8888

eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka
```

Then here is the Zuul server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaClient
@Slf4j
public class ZuulServerApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulServerApplication.class, args);
        log.info("-- ZuulServerApplication started --");
    }
}
```

and the application.yml for Zuul

```
server:
  port: 7777

eureka:
  instance:
    appname: zuul-server
  client:
    serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka

zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
    file-management:
      path: /file-management/**
      serviceId: file-management
```

and a microservice file-management:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableSwagger2
@Slf4j
public class FileManagementApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileManagementApplication.class, args);
        log.info("-- FileManagement started --");
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
... some other configs
server:
  port: 8081
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: file-management
  client:
    serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka
```

I have this problem for a couple of days, Any help would be great appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I did a research, I solved my problem. I put my solution here, and hope this may help people meet the same problem.

How I solved:

1. in the file-management `application.yml` added:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: file-management
```

2. in the `zuul` `application.yml` added:

```yaml
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: true
```

Then it works.

The reason is lots of toturials and examples are based on some old version, so I guess in the newer version they did some adjust.

So for the people meet the same problem like me, please make sure the documents or examples you reading are match the version you are using. And hope this answer may help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had any problem with this configuration:

```
 server:
    port: 8881

 eureka:
   client:
     eureka-connection-idle-timeout-seconds: 60
     serviceUrl:
       defaultZone: http://localhost:8882/eureka/
     healthcheck:
       enabled: true
```

You can check my repo [here](https://github.com/eberttc/spring-cloud-demo).

Also could you try commenting  appname: file-management and aligning defaultZone.Sometimes yml properties not load if dont have right formatting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will have a try then give the feedback.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. I still can not solve my problem. But thanks all the same.